# Java: probability of random values being equal

Tags: java, numerical-methods

This code

```
java.util.Random r = new java.util.Random();
double a = r.nextDouble();
...
double b = r.nextDouble();
```

produces two random values between 0.0 and 1.0.
What is the probability of `a == b`?

(how many distinct double values are there between 0.0 and 1.0?)

Comment: This has already been answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978930/how-many-double-numbers-are-there-between-0-0-and-1-0#2978945

Comment: The probability of a==b don't have to depend on number of values between 0 and 1 :) If I were to choose, I could have thrown a dice, and decide which value I'll return each time. It will be random, but always the same :)