# Better algorithm generating random numbers in JS

Tags: javascript, random

My goal is to generate random integers between 1 and 100 in JavaScript.

I'm currently using this:

```js
const random = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100)
console.log(random)
```

But I saw a lot of places an alternate solution,

```js
const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1)
console.log(random)
```

which produces the same results.

**My question is that:**

Why is the second code better (if better at all) than my first code?
Isn't it better to perform one operation rather than two (`Math.floor()` and `+1`)?

Thanks for your time and answers!

Comment: The first example produces numbers between 0 (inclusive) and 100 (inclusive), the second produces numbers between 1 (inclusive) and 100 (inclusive). They are not the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one notable difference between these two

```
Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100)
Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1)
```

The first has a theoretical possibility to produce 0 with a very tiny probability, the second not.

Answer (score 1):

Both produce nearly the same result. You could take a quantitative test and have a look to the count of the drawn numbers.

```js
const
    getRandomCeil = () => Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100),       // 0 ... 100 0 is less likely
    getRandomFloor = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1); // 1 ... 100

var i,
    count = { ceil: {}, floor: {} };

for (i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    value = getRandomCeil();
    count.ceil[value] = (count.ceil[value] || 0) + 1;
    value = getRandomFloor();
    count.floor[value] = (count.floor[value] || 0) + 1;
}
console.log(count);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: You modified OP's formula.

Comment: What if `Math.random` returns 0?

Comment: i did, but it is negligible.

Comment: @JonasWilms, right. but how is the probability of it?

Comment: @nina I guess roughly 1 to 2**63 (64 bit float, assuming a negative exponent sign)

Comment: Regardless of how small the probability, they do not produce the same numbers. Getting or not getting 0 instead of a positive number is a very important distinction.

Comment: @NinaScholz As some people wrote, the first method can return zero, so they are not exactly the same, but thanks for the clear visualisation example!

Comment: @everybody I see it now! I was unable to find the difference on my own, but as you pointed out, I understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[`Math.random`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) produces number in the range `[0, 1)` which means ***0 is inclusive*** and 1 is not. Looking at the two extreme cases:

```
// When Math.random() returns 0
Math.ceil(0 * 100)         // returns 0 since ceiling of 0 is 0
Math.floor(0 * 100 + 1)    // returns 1

// When Math.random() returns 0.999999...
Math.ceil(0.999999 * 100)  // returns 100
Math.floor(0.999999 + 1)   // returns 100
```

The `ceil` variant has the potential of returning 0 when random function returns exactly 0; [although the probability is very<del>, very</del> little](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978930/how-many-double-numbers-are-there-between-0-0-and-1-0).