# JavaScript - Difference between random function results

Tags: javascript

Is there a difference between the results of `Math.floor(Math.random() * x) + 1` and `Math.ceil(Math.random() * x)`?

Comment: If `Math.random() * x` is a integer they will have different values. However, the chance of that is small.

Comment: Are you asking if there is any difference in the spread/likelihood of the random numbers this produces?

Comment: The difference is the first can never return `0` and the second can.

Comment: Math.random gives a number between 0 included and 1 excluded. Multiplying it by x gives a number between 0 included and x excluded. Therefore doing Math.floor + 1 or Math.ceil on that number gives the same result ( Random integer between 1 included and X included )

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Better algorithm generating random numbers in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55172070/better-algorithm-generating-random-numbers-in-js)

Comment: @XavierB. incorrect - `Math.floor(0 + 1) == 1`, but `Math.ceil(0) == 0`

Answer (score 2):

[`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) produces floating point values [in the interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396290/what-does-this-square-bracket-and-parenthesis-bracket-notation-mean-first1-last) **[0, 1)** (from zero *inclusive* to one *exclusive*). This means that there is a slight difference between the two approaches:

`Math.ceil(Math.random() * x)` will produce integers in the interval **[0, x]** (from zero *inclusive* to `x` *inclusive*). This is because `Math.ceil(0)` will return a zero. Although the chance of getting that is extremely small.

```js
function minRandom() { return 0; }
function maxRandom() { return 0.9999999; }

const x = 10;
console.log("min:", Math.ceil(minRandom() * x));
console.log("max:", Math.ceil(maxRandom() * x));
```

`Math.floor(Math.random() * x) + 1` will produce integers in the interval **[1, x]** (from one *inclusive* to `x` *inclusive*). This is because `Math.floor(Math.random() * x)` itself produces integers in the interval **[0, x-1]** (zero *inclusive* to `x-1` *inclusive*).

```js
function minRandom() { return 0; }
function maxRandom() { return 0.9999999; }

const x = 10;
console.log("min:", Math.floor(minRandom() * x) + 1);
console.log("max:", Math.floor(maxRandom() * x) + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a difference.

There is a chance, albeit a *very very small one*, that the second version could unexpectedly return zero.

This happens if `Math.random()` itself returns exactly 0.0, which it legally can.

Comment: I'm not really sure it's unexpected. Well, unless you never wanted a zero. But it's a totally valid output.

Comment: @VLAZ kinda - it's certainly valid, but it might surprise some people (including some of the other commentators here).

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Any output can be a surprise if you don't know how something works.